# Question closed as Not A Real Question

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, not-a-real-question, recently-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538377/easiest-way-to-autolink-text-and-add-class) was closed as Not A Real Question, which states:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

It is not difficult to tell what is being asked. The question is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical; and it was perfectly answered by me 5 days ago. So why has it been closed 18 hours ago?

Comment: It's certainly incomplete in the sense that you have shown no effort or research of your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer might be a good one, but it's a PHP answer on a question that doesn't even mention PHP. The OP does mention PHP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538377/easiest-way-to-autolink-text-and-add-class#comment16883175_12538377):

> i wrote some php with regex but its failing miserably and was hoping there was something else out there that could do this already maybe in an easier way.. which is why i asked here. bad idea.

...and was [asked to share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538377/easiest-way-to-autolink-text-and-add-class#comment16883979_12538377) their PHP code:

> @user1568736 - Then post your PHP and regex and we'll help you figure out what's wrong.

...but they didn't (yet?).

When examining whether a question fits or not, comments aren't really that important, if the OP responds to the comment and share their PHP code in the question, I could see the question getting re-opened. But right now I have to agree with the close voters, it is ambiguous, vague, and incomplete. If you want you could (and should) help the OP fix their question, and if that happens you should flag it for moderation attention and ask for it to be re-opened (if it doesn't start getting re-open votes naturally, as any edit brings new attention to every post).

We do expect every question to show some prior research / effort, even if it's minimal, and Not A Real Question closures are commonly applied when there's none.

Answer (score 5):

> It is not difficult to tell what is being asked.

There is nothing asked, there's only "gimme me the codez".

> The question is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad...

Would you like a solution in JavaScript, PHP, Perl, Python, Bash...with a backend in MySQL, SQLite, plain textfiles...?!

> ...rhetorical...

Yes, it's not.

> ...and it was perfectly answered by me 5 days ago.

That speaks against you, not for the question. We should not encourage bad questions by answering them.

And to answer to the downvotes, it clearly fits the downvote-tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 4):

The NARQ description doesn't cover all possibilities. The comments on that question describe very well why it was closed.

The fact that your answer may be right doesn't stop it being a bad question.

Answer (score 4):

It is overly broad, as it doesn't even use a tag for the language/framework/technology for which the user is interested. One of the comments left from the OP says he tried with PHP, but  the comment also says:

> [I] was hoping there was something else out there that could do this already[,] maybe in an easier way.

The fact the OP didn't use any language tag, and wrote that comment make me think the OP is interested in any solution, as long as it is an easier way (and somebody shows him the code to use, I guess).
The fact the OP said to want an easier way makes me thing the question is rather subjective; what is easier for somebody could not be easier for somebody else.

Not constructive could have been the other reason to close the question, but really answering the question requires expertise. It is not clear what expertise is required (PHP, Drupal, Ruby, Python, Scala, name-your-prefered-language), and that is the reason for closing the question as not a real question.